# Laravel get related data from 3 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: `users, emails,attachments`. User table is connected with emails by user_id. Emails table is connected with attachments by email_id.

My question is: How should I make it look eloquent in laravel to get all users their emails and their attachments? (I know how get all user and they emails but I don't know how to add attachments.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your database relationship,you may declare a relationship method in your `Email` model, for example:

```php
// One to One (If Email has only one attachment)
public function attachment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Attachment::class);
}
```

Otherwise:

```php
// One to Many (If Email contains more than one attachment)
public function attachments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class);
}
```

To retrieve the related attachment(s) from `Email` model when reading a user using id, you may try something like this:

```php
$user = User::with('email.attachment')->find(1); // For One-to-One
$user = User::with('email.attachments')->find(1); // For One-to-Many
```

Hope you've already declared the relationship method in the `User` model for `Email` model using the method name `email`.

Note: make sure, you have used right namespace for models. It may work if you've done everything right and followed the `Laravel` convention, otherwise do some research. Also [check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Hello again, I have one more question. How should look query if I wanna get users and their attachments(without emails)(users is connected to email and email is connected to attachments)? Now I just added  another key for table attachments (user_id) but I think that there is option to get data without this additional key.

Comment: In this case, you can create an `atachments` relationship method in your `Model` same way you've created in `Email` model.

Comment: Thanks buddy! You really saved a lot of time.